# How do I add proper longclick and normal click at the same time to my button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android-button

I am testing the longclick and the short click features for a simple standalone project. What I am planning to do is, when I click on a button/header it will call a fragment , but when I long click viz., even without releasing my finger , I want the popup to show. My current implementation shows the popup no matter I do a long click or a short click. I would like toshow popup only upon long click and not upon short click. Also, through the popup select menu,I want to trigger a related fragment to the options selected.Is there a way to do this?Can you modify my existing code to reflect that?
Thanks!
Here's my code:
Mainactivity.java:

```
package com.example.longclick;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button  btnList;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        btnList = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnListSample);
        btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Personal Lists", "Shared Lists"};
    AlertDialog.Builder listBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    listBuilder.setTitle("Manage Categories");
    listBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertList = listBuilder.create();
    alertList.show();    
   }
  }); 


    }
}
```

and associated xml:
activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


  <Button 
   android:text="Lists Header" 
   android:id="@+id/btnListSample" 

   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
  </Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should implement your own code but here are the basics

```
btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vi) {

        }
});

btnList.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            return false;
        }

});
```

Comment: got it working, thanks! Just to know, is there a way to dismiss the call just by touching outside the popup?

Comment: popup.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your button a text view or something else. Then for that object, add two listeners:

[onLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

and

[onClickListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

you could try adding the onLongClickListener to the button object but I'm not sure if that is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

you should add OnLongClickListener to the button:

```
  btnList.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {   
   @Override
   public void onLongClick(View v) {
    //what you want to do 
        }   
  });
```

You can call start an activity from the dialog, and make fragment transaction too, but i don't understand what exactly you want to do.